# Как правильно увеличивать на 100 css свойство элемента?

Tags: javascript

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("relax");
var next = document.getElementById("next");

next.onclick = function(){
    slider.style.left += 100 + "%";
  }
```

```html
<article id="relax" style="left:0%; position: absolute;"><img src="1.jpg"></article>
<button id="next">next</button>
```

Как правильно записать, что бы при нажатии оно увеличивало свойства left
на 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы ищите через `querySelectorAll`, это коллекция.
upd.`slider.style.left` возвращаемое значение строка, у вас в примере вернется 0%,можно воспользоваться `parseInt(slider.style.left)` и далее увеличить как Вам нужно.

Comment: Исправил document.getElementById